# git track all file on the computer

Tags: git

﻿I have a problem about my terminal and iterm2 on Macbook pro.

Just like normal, I was coding my shell program, my terminal starting pop-up and alert:

- "Terminal would like to access files in your Download folder"
- "Terminal would like to access files in your photo "
- "Terminal would like to access files in your remindar" ...etc

I open iterm2 or terminal, it used to be opened very fast, but now it have to wait about 10 or 20 seconds for the input field show.

[iterm2 screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhCxN.png)

[iterm2 screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFqzY.png)

I guess the git had track all my file on the computer, or it might be other problem.

Could any one help me about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer about this problem!

This problem was happen because the bad git local repo, that repo track all file on your computer disk, so it will delay the performance when you want to open the terminal.

You can go to the right folder and delete the .git foder, so that problem will be fixed!

refer page: https://superuser.com/questions/1484086/git-status-lists-all-the-files-on-my-pc